# Multiple MySQL versions in MAMP Pro?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, multiple-versions

Is it possible to run multiple versions of MySQL in MAMP Pro?

I love MAMP Pro, but I recently updated to v4 – which auto upgraded MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6 – and now I can't migrate Wordpress sites to live hosting accounts anymore (e.g. GoDaddy) because it spits out an error about "Unknown collation". No hosting providers seem to be running 5.6 yet.

I guess the lesson here is 'tough luck, you should've read the upgrade announcement carefully'. But that doesn't really help me.

I know I can probably just export the databases in a format that works, and import them via phpMyAdmin, but I use BackupBuddy so I'd rather stick with something that just works.

Any suggestions on how best to avoid this in future? Any better alternatives to MAMP that will allow more granular control over things like PHP and MySQL versions? I'm only a designer, so I'm not interested/capable in going in-depth with the command line or anything like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a downgrade path from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/downgrading-to-previous-series.html

Alternatively, and assuming that you've backed up your previous MAMP instance database info, you can roll back to the previous version of MAMP.

Docker is a better solution for mixing and matching multiple language versions, but stating that you're "not interested/capable" in working in the command line severely limits what you can do with development environments.

And there are good hosts that are using 5.6, especially hosts that focus on WordPress. GoDaddy is the lowest common denominator and isn't indicative of the larger hosting landscape.

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate the response. Rolling back MAMP is certainly an option, but then you don't get the benefit of bug fixes, etc. I'll take a look at Docker and see if it's something that will work for me.